# fixed menu in mobile web application that stays on screen even if other elements have more then 100% width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so, I have a fixed menu with a `width: 100%` on a mobile web application
[pic of the nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNDvY.png). I want to add in the container div an image that will be a bigger size than the screen so that the user could scroll to see all the parts of the picture.
Once I add the picture the screen goes crazy [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJoR3.png). the menu is pushed to the side and gets smaller then before, doesn't cover the whole width and the image goes on top.
I gave the menu index-z: 999, but that still *doesn't fix the menu staying on one side of the screen as soon as the image gets out of the screen borders or is given a width that's larger than 100%.*
I tried to put the nav in another div and play with `display: absolute` but nothing seems to work.

my code:

```css
#navContainer {
    height: 10vw;
    background-color: var(--main-darkGray);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#navAbsolute {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
}
.myMap {
    /*max-width: 550px;
    position: relative;   
    padding: 0;*/
}

#mapImage {
    /*display: block;*/
    /*height: 100%;
    width: 100%;*/
    z-index: -10;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

```html
         <div id="navAbsolute">

            <div id="navContainer">
                <span id="menuIcon" style="font-size:7vw; cursor:pointer; color: var(--main-cream); padding-right: 4vw;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

                <div id="goldShield" class="shields">
                    <img src="images/goldShield.png" class="shImages" />
                    <span id="goldScore" class="score">500</span>
                </div>
                <div id="silverShield" class="shields">
                    <img src="images/silverShield.png" class="shImages" />
                    <span id="silverScore" class="score">50</span>
                </div>
                <div id="bronzeShield" class="shields">
                    <img src="images/bronzeShield.png" class="shImages" />
                    <span id="bronzeScore" class="score">5</span>
                </div>
                <div id="timer"><p id="seconds">00</p>:<p id="minutes">00</p></div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div class="myMap">
            <img id="mapImage" src="images/map.PNG" />
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Does set #navAbsolute  to `max-width: 100%;` is solve your problem?

Comment: If navContainer is fixed you don't need navAbsolute outside of it.
Just try to add width: 100% to navContainer. It relates to body tag (fixed positioning, absolute relates to parent relative div).

Comment: I tried to do this. Didn't work.